How can I verify that a specific program has an object library to automate it, such as Excel?
The question that has really puzzled me for a long time is: How can I verify that a specific program on Windows has an object library for communicating with it and automating tasks, similar to MS Excel on Windows?
Without the need to search the documentation or browse the internet, as some programs are only superficially documented.
I tried searching in this community and on the internet for answers to my question, but I did not find any, or perhaps I did not know the appropriate keyword.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much

How could that possibly be doable?  Interrogating the program could at most tell you whether it had some sort of DLL-exported interface, but that interface could look like anything and might or might not be relevant.  And automation could be over sockets or shared memory or the file system itself.

@DavisHerring  - How can I interrogate the program? Step by step please, with an example if possible, including Notepad++

@DavisHerring - Please, what is the difference between socket based API and DLL file based API? Do we call both APIs in general? Isn't there a specific name for each type?


"DLL file based API" such as : Win API,   while: "socket based AP" such as : paypal API.


@DavisHerring - You can explain how I find the Notepad++ API, without consulting endless documentation and search results.

Sorry, I thought (because of “including”) you meant using Notepad++ as the editor for writing this code, not as the program being examined.  Searching for “executable export” will find some things, but that’s the easy part.
